# "ng build --configuration= staging or production or demo" command throwing error after building

Tags: angular, build, frontend, angular9

I am trying to build my angular 9 project for different-different environments. But when I tried to execute these commands **" ng build --configuration = staging"** or **" ng build --configuration = demo"** or **" ng build --configuration = production"** it is throwing me error when I am executing the **dist** folder. But when I execute **ng build** command it building and executing.

This is the error :

[image]

Things I have tried:

1. I have made the code optimizer(terser-plugin) to false and after that, I have got this error :
   [image]

**Note:** there is no code error, no variable defination is missing as **ng build** command is working and executing my project

Comment: try building without optimizer and with sourcemaps enabled. you should see a better error call stack

Comment: @Andrei The second image is the error I have got after turning off the optimser

Comment: but did you enabled `sourcemaps`?

Comment: @Andrei No Haven't tried that i'll try to do that

Comment: Are you using angular2-cookie in your project?

Comment: @MFuatNUROĞLU No

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/4752

Comment: Please try this and edit your post with the new error message if changes
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/4752#issuecomment-392100468

Comment: @MFuatNUROĞLU the 2nd image in my post is the error I am getting after ur suggestion.

Comment: ng build --prod
have you tried this ?

Comment: Have you solved your problem:
`ng build --prod` will help you to find what causes the error